# Unable to run dreamhost cron job to send emails on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, cron, dreamhost

These are the steps that I followed to set up my CRON :

1. `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` added in `wp-config.php` file
2. Installed `WP Control` and Added a Hook `lead_mail_gun`.
3. Added following code in my code snippets.

```
add_action( 'lead_mail_gun', 'cron_test_function' );

function cron_test_function() {
    $email = 'my-mail-id';
    $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

    wp_mail('my-mail-id', 'WP Crontrol', 'WP Crontrol rocks!', $headers);
}
```

4. I can see my funciton in the list of CRON events list.
5. Also I can see `The DISABLE_WP_CRON constant is set to true. WP-Cron spawning is disabled.` which confirms that default CRON is off
6. In my dreamhost I added a CRON Job with the following command `/usr/local/php72/bin/php /home/path_to_my_cron_file/wp-cron.php`
    running every 10 mins.

I am getting no emails. What can be the cause of emails not being sent ?

> I have tested that I can send emails though my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix was simple.

Use the following in the command section of CRON.

`curl https://www.example.com/wp-cron.php`